# Using a Python Module in Spyder rather than Command Line

Tags: python, spyder

Have a very beginner question here.
I have downloaded the module "pdf-diff"(https://pypi.org/project/pdf-diff/) for Python and can get it to execute in the terminal fine. However, I wish to call the command in a Python script that I am writing. The script is comparing multiple pdf files over a for loop and I want it to generate one of the pdf-diff reports for each one.

How can I find which argument to call in my Spyder console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As I checked the `pdf-diff` module, it seems it just running using the command-line. also, the owner [JoshData](https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-diff) said that he doesn't maintain the project anymore. So if you want to use in python you have 2 choices:

1 -  using bash command in python using `subprocess` module.

2 - install `pdf_diff` and use this code

```
from pdf_diff import command_line

# 'strike,underline' for style is the default value
# 'png' for format is the default value
# 0 , 100 , 900 for top_margin ,bottom_margin  , width are default values
style = 'strike,underline'.split(',')
format = 'png'
changes = command_line.compute_changes('/path/to/pdf/file/1.pdf', '/path/to/pdf/file/2.pdf',top_margin=0,bottom_margin=100)
img = command_line.render_changes(changes, style, width=900)
img.save('/path/for/saving/name', format.upper())
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import it as a module in Spyder console. and then call it.

Something like this:

```
import pdf-diff

pdf-diff **argument**
```